# How to access static interface member when the interface is implemented explicitly

Tags: c#, methods, interface, static, abstract

I wonder if I found the right solution how to access static property/method of the interface when the interface is implemented explicitly.

In .NET 7 interface can define static abstract members. For example **System.Numerics.INumberBase** interface define:

```
public static abstract TSelf One { get; }
```

This interface is **explicitly** implemented by various numeric types, e.g. **System.Int32**.

```
/// <inheritdoc cref="INumberBase{TSelf}.One" />
static int INumberBase<int>.One => One;
```

Now trying to access **int.One** value.

Here is what I tried:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Does not compile - because One is implemented explicitly
        // Compiler: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'One' 
        Console.WriteLine(int.One);

        // Does not compile
        // Compiler: A static virtual or abstract interface member can be accessed only on a type parameter.
        Console.WriteLine(System.Numerics.INumberBase<int>.One);
        
        // Compiles
        Console.WriteLine(GetOne<int>());
    }
    
    private static T GetOne<T>() where T : System.Numerics.INumberBase<T> => T.One;
}
```

Is the **GetOne** method the only solution (without using reflection) or am I missing something?

Comment: Good question. I'm also wondering about the design decision behind the explicit interface implementation.

Comment: Great question! I am stumped too by the lack of a "clean" way to access interface static members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was discussed [in the comments](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4436#issuecomment-1236228833) to the proposal for static abstract members in interfaces - currently there are no other options except for the generic indirection (i.e. `GetOne<T>()` approach) or using reflection for explicitly implemented static abstract interface members.

Just for completeness - using reflection (with not perfect search by member name) approach:

```cs
var properties = typeof(int).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
var propertyInfo = properties.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.EndsWith(".One"));
var one = (int)propertyInfo.GetValue(null);
```